# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 laptop lid options missing

Tags: gnome, suspend, laptop, lid

I moved from Unity to **Gnome** and there seems to be no option to change the action for when I close the lid of my laptop. I found a workaround using dconf Editor, but I really wanted to know why there isn't an option under power management in the setting (or anywhere else in the settings).
Is it somewhere else and I'm not seeing it? 
There's no option at all? Why?

Thank you!

Comment: I just looked at mine, and I don't see it either. I also came from Unity.

Comment: You can use dconf Editor if your really need to change those options, but I still would like to know why they took them away, if anyone knows.

Comment: To save me some time hunting for it, which value needs to get changed?

Comment: lid-close-ac-action and lid-close-battery-action

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that `GNOME Tweak Tool` has these settings.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now.

Comment: Maybe someone can post an answer based on comments?